# Converting Int to String LinqToENTITIES

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have some issue with the Convert.ToInt32 / Parse.Int, my column at DB is varchar type and I need to compare with an Int32 Type with >= operator. Here's some piece of the code I'm using, Hope you can help me.

```
var municipio = this.MunicipioRepository.Find(x => ((Int32.Parse(cep) >=   
                                                    Int32.Parse(x.CEPInicial))) &&
                            ((Int32.Parse(cep) <= Int32.Parse(x.CEPFinal))));
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: Initially, you don't have to make use of both `Convett.ToInt32` and `Int32.Parse`. What's the type of `CEPInicial` and `CEPFinal`? I suppose that `cep` is a string that can be converted without any error or parsed to an `int`. Correct?

Comment: Sorry that's result of some experiments actually I'm using only Parse, CEPInicial and CEPFinal are string type at DB

Comment: "some issue"... please be more specific.

Comment: I was specific.... That code simply don't work, the framework don't let me use convert.ToInt32 or Int32.Parse on a Query.

Comment: @FelippeRodrigues Well, you didn't say that, and "don't let me use" is not specific either. If you get exceptions, always show them in your question. I could have guessed all this of course, but I don't know if your `Find` method works on the original EF `DbSet<T>`. Nobody likes to answer a question if they don't know *for sure* what's going on.

Comment: @Rawling This is the reverse case. It's actually quite a tough problem for which I couldn't find a good duplicate. EF doesn't allow methods like `Convert.ToInt32` or `int.Parse` and it has no canonic alternatives for it. And comparing the strings themselves is not the same as a numeric comparison. The only thing is, the OP should describe it in more detail.

Comment: @GertArnold ... Convert int to string in the title, convert string to int in the questions. \o/

Comment: Haven't tested it but in theory you might register the built-in CONVERT function in your model and use it: http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/registering-sql-server-built-in-functions-to-entity-framework-code-first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is "you can't".

The long answer is: EF tries to translate the expression tree that you make using the various Linq methods into Sql.

The EF provider does not know how to transalte Int32.Parse or Convert.ToInt32 into SQL, and that's what's blocking you.

The only thing you can do, but it might be a performance killer, is to read all the items you need to compare from DB, materialize them and from that point onwards your queries will be Linq2Objects and not Linq2Entities anymore, allowing you to use anything you want.

In your example, though, this would result in materializing the whole table. If the table is a small lookup no problem, but otherwise this can really kill your application.

To achieve this just place a `ToArray()` or `ToList()` call before the `Find`.

If you, however, have the chance to work on the database, you can do a much more clean thing. You can create a computed column on your table that returns the converted string value to integer, then you map this new column in your EF model and use it for the comparison, this way you can just compare INT to INT without any casting needed and it would work and be much better performance-wise. Of course your `cep` parameter should be an integer too, and you should convert it outside the Linq query so you can use it without any problem.

Comment: Now I'm really curious about the downvote. My answer is correct, and is rather complete. Not that I care about it, just curious.

Comment: I am well aware of the "SqlFunctions" class and there's a solid reason I have not mentioned it. Linq queries are meant to be reusable and abstracted away from the actual provider lying underneath. The "SqlFunctions" class resides in System.Data.Objects.SqlClient namespace, which is more than specific to the underlying provider. So I do not consider it a good choice to use it in your Linq queries.

Comment: I'll consider and will try to talk to my boss, maybe we can change the DB a little. Just to be clear it was not me that downvoted you.

Thanks for your time and your very complete and clear answer!